# How can I retrieve contacts/emails from things like MSN, Twitter, Facebook, GMail , etc...?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, email, social-networking, contacts

I'm building an application that gives users the option to send out an email notification to their friends.

The options I would like to give them for this are to:

- manually write down which emails they would like to send to
- choose contacts from a list of ones already in the database for that user
- choose all contacts from facebook, twitter, digg, gmail, or msn to send the email to

Is there any way I can retrieve all of the email addresses for a certain contact from these different websites?

For example, if I chose the option to send out email notification and I wanted to send it to all of my friends on my facebook account, how could I do this? (Remembering that the user is interacting with a completely separate website and should not have to go onto facebook to send this emails)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google contacts api: http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/
Windows Live contacts api: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463989.aspx

Facebook's apis are here: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API

Answer (score 0):

For each websites (twitter, facebook, etc.) use their API for accessing contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Russau was faster with the Google contacts API. For sending Gmail messges there is also a third-party API [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmail4j/). Actually I thought that also Google released one, but I couldn't find it at the moment.

**\Edit:**
[This](http://googledataapis.blogspot.com/2009/06/new-contacts-data-api-features-are-here.html) might be relevant too.

Comment: i guess you could sent gmail message via IMAP too?